# views.py for extended user model by onetoone to add profile information

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, one-to-one, django-users

I am extending `User` model to add profile information using onetoone relation. The user should be able to change the basic user profile info.
What should be the `views` to add such functionality?

Here is my model

**Models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='No description field')
city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Location not added')
phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='',blank= True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/profile/%Y%/%m/%d', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Here is my form

**forms.py**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta():
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ['description', 'city', 'phone', 'image']
```

What should I include in my views?

**views.py**

```
@login_required()
def edit_profile(request):
pass
```

I want to update the model the extended **UserProfile** instance in a way that the previous info gets overwritten and the new information is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the `UserForm` in the view like any other usual form.

here what you need to do:

**views.py**

```
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # don't forget to pass request.FILES since you have imageField
        form = UserForm(request.POST,
                        request.FILES,
                        instance=request.user.userprofile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('to_user_profile_url'))
    else:
        form = UserForm(instance=request.user.userprofile)
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'edit_profile_template', context)
```